# Why is Router used like normal function instead of constructor in express 4.x?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url-routing

I am newbie trying to understand Express 4.x routing and I am reading their guide at: http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html

In the last paragraph it says following:

> The express.Router class can be used to create modular mountable route
>   handlers. A Router instance is a complete middleware and routing
>   system

and accompanying code is:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
```

Why is this `express.Router` constructor called like ordinary function without the `new` operator? They say in documentation it's a class, they named it according to javascript style (capital first letter) but they (and all other examples online) use it as an ordinary function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some people like to support the functional style in addition to traditional instantiation. This is done by adding a simple check like this at the top of the function:

```
function Router() {
  if (!(this instanceof Router))
    return new Router();

  // ...
}
```

This allows the support of both types of invocations (with `new` and without).